# three.js scroll

Tags: scroll, three.js

I have had this problem with every three.js scene i've created so far, but here is one example (the one i'm currently working on). If you put too much html code, it will go under the scene but i can't scroll down to see it. How can i allow page scrolling ? Here is one page example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" xml:lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>



 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        

<script src="lib/Three.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="lib/Detector.js"></script>
<script src="lib/stats.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/THREEx/THREEx.WindowResize.js"></script>
<script src="lib/THREEx/THREEx.FUllScreen.js"></script>
<script src="lib/TrackballControls.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
  body
{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:  gray;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
#center
{
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px; width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index:100;
}

#center h1
{

    font-size:60px;
}

#container
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

  </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container"></div>


 </body>

 <script>
// MAIN

console.log("Main.js");
if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

// global variables

var container, scene, camera, renderer, stats, controls;

// custom variables 

var t = THREE;
var cube;

// to keep track of the mouse position
var projector, INTERSECTED, mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 },

// an array to store our particles in
particles = [];

init();
animate();

function init()
{


    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // camera
    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
    scene.add(camera);
    camera.position.set(0,0,800);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    // container
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // stats
    stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
    stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
    container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

    // events 
    THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
    THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode : 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });

    // initialize object to perform world/screen calculations
    projector = new THREE.Projector();

    // CUSTOM

    // Cubes

    x = window.innerWidth / 5;
    y =  window.innerHeight / 10;
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
    console.log(window.innerHeight);
    var geometry = new t.CubeGeometry(125,125,125);
    var material = new t.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xCCCCCC});
    cube = new t.Mesh(geometry, material);
    cube.name = "cube";

    scene.add(cube);
    cube.position.set(-x,-y,0);

    x = window.innerWidth;
    y =  window.innerHeight / 10;

    var geometry2 = new t.CubeGeometry(125,125,125);
    var material2 = new t.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xCCCCCC});
    cube2 = new t.Mesh(geometry2, material2);
    scene.add(cube2);

    cube2.name = "cube2";
    cube2.position.set(0,-y,0);


    x = window.innerWidth / 5;
    y =  window.innerHeight / 10;

    var geometry3 = new t.CubeGeometry(125,125,125);
    var material3 = new t.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xCCCCCC});
    cube3 = new t.Mesh(geometry3, material3);
    cube3.name = "cube3";

    scene.add(cube3);
    cube3.position.set(x,-y,0);

    // particles

    makeParticles(); 


// Mouse events
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false ); 
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown, false ); 


}


// called when the mouse moves
function onMouseMove( event ) 
{
// store the mouseX and mouseY position 
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}

function onMouseDown( event ) 
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );

    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 )
    {
        console.log(INTERSECTED.name);
        if(INTERSECTED.name == "cube")
        {
            page("real");
        }
    }
}

function animate() 
{
    cube.rotation.y +=0.005;
    cube.rotation.x -=0.005;
    cube2.rotation.y +=0.005;
    cube2.rotation.x -=0.005;
    cube3.rotation.y +=0.005;
    cube3.rotation.x -=0.005;
    //textMesh.rotation.y +=0.005;

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();   
    update();   
}

                // creates a random field of Particle objects

function makeParticles() 
{ 

var particle, material; 

    // we're gonna move from z position -1000 (far away) 
    // to 1000 (where the camera is) and add a random particle at every pos. 
    for ( var zpos= -1000; zpos < 1000; zpos+=20 ) 
    {

    // we make a particle material and pass through the 
    // colour and custom particle render function we defined. 
    material = new THREE.ParticleCanvasMaterial( {  program: particleRender } );
    // make the particle
    particle = new THREE.Particle(material);

    // give it a random x and y position between -500 and 500
    particle.position.x = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;
    particle.position.y = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;

    // set its z position
    particle.position.z = zpos;

    // scale it up a bit
    particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 10;

    // add it to the scene
    scene.add( particle );

    // and to the array of particles. 
    particles.push(particle); 
    }
}

// there isn't a built in circle particle renderer 
// so we have to define our own. 

function particleRender( context ) 
{

// we get passed a reference to the canvas context
context.beginPath();
// and we just have to draw our shape at 0,0 - in this
// case an arc from 0 to 2Pi radians or 360º - a full circle!
context.arc( 0, 0, 0.2, 2,  Math.PI * 4, true );
context.fillStyle = "white";
context.fill();
};

    // moves all the particles dependent on mouse position

function updateParticles() 
{ 

    // iterate through every particle
    for(var i=0; i<particles.length; i++) 
    {

    particle = particles[i]; 

    // and move it forward dependent on the mouseY position. 
    particle.position.z +=  250 * 0.02;

    // if the particle is too close move it to the back
    if(particle.position.z>1000) particle.position.z-=2000; 

    }

}

function render()
{
renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function update()
{
updateParticles();
stats.update();


    // find intersections

    // create a Ray with origin at the mouse position
    //   and direction into the scene (camera direction)
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );

    // create an array containing all objects in the scene with which the ray intersects
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children );

    // INTERSECTED = the object in the scene currently closest to the camera 
    //      and intersected by the Ray projected from the mouse position    

    // if there is one (or more) intersections
    if ( intersects.length > 0 )
    {
        // if the closest object intersected is not the currently stored intersection object
        if ( intersects[ 0 ].object != INTERSECTED) 
        {
            // restore previous intersection object (if it exists) to its original scale
            if ( INTERSECTED )  
            {
                INTERSECTED.scale.x = INTERSECTED.currentscale.x;
                INTERSECTED.scale.y = INTERSECTED.currentscale.y;
                INTERSECTED.scale.z = INTERSECTED.currentscale.z;
            }
            // store reference to closest object as current intersection object
            INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
            // store scale of closest object (for later restoration)
            scalex = INTERSECTED.scale.x;
            scaley = INTERSECTED.scale.y;
            scalez = INTERSECTED.scale.z;

            INTERSECTED.currentscale = { x : scalex , y : scaley, z : scalez };
            // set a new scale for closest object
            INTERSECTED.scale.x = INTERSECTED.scale.y = INTERSECTED.scale.z = 1.5;


        }
    } 

    else // there are no intersections
    {
        // restore previous intersection object (if it exists) to its original scale
        if ( INTERSECTED ) 
        {
            INTERSECTED.scale.x = INTERSECTED.currentscale.x;
            INTERSECTED.scale.y = INTERSECTED.currentscale.y;
            INTERSECTED.scale.z = INTERSECTED.currentscale.z;
        }

        // remove previous intersection object reference
        //     by setting current intersection object to "nothing"
        INTERSECTED = null;
    }

}



// Pour charger une page dynamiquement
    function page(page){
    $("body").animate({opacity:0},1000, function(){
    $("body").empty();
    $("body").load(page +'.html');
    $("body").animate({opacity:1},1000, function(){

            });
        });
}


 </script>






</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

That is at least one part of your problem, as it specifies that the page contents should not scroll but be truncated. You may need to change other parts of the CSS to get the layout you want, but this certainly needs to be removed.

Comment: Yeah, this was definitely the problem. This is rather funny that it was only a css issue. Thanks for your help.
The other problem now, is that the mouse hover on cubes works on the whole page Y line. Which means the mousehover action is treated even if the mouse doesn't directly hover the cube, it works if the mouse stands at the relative position of the cube to the page. How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: You need to accept this answer by clicking on the check mark and post a new issue if you are having additional problems.